# React Native:Module RCTEventEmitter is not a registered callable module (calling receiveTouches)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to work with react-navigation, but have some problems. I cant see what is wrong. How can I solve this problem?

What I have tried so far:

- Restarted emulator (PC)
- Rewrite all code
- Created new a project and tried that code there too.

  ```
  import React, {Component} from 'react';
  import {StyleSheet,Text,View} from 'react-native';
  import {createStackNavigator,createAppContainer} from "react-navigation";



  class HomeScreen extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>Home</Text>
          </View>
      );
    }
  }

  export default  class App extends  Component{
    render(){
      return(
    <AppContainer />
      );
    }

  }

  const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Home:{
      screen: HomeScreen
    }


  });
  const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

  const styles=StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
      flex:1,
      justifyContent:'center',
      alignItems:'center',
      backgroundColor:'#F5FCFF',
    }

  });
  ```

Comment: The code looks fine, did you follow the whole https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html guide?

Comment: I open it another a emulator, and now just have blank a screen

Comment: I runned your code on and it works, showing a blank header and text "Home" in the center of the screen. What RN version are you using? Is it an Android emulator or an iOS emulator?

Comment: "react-native": "0.60.4"

Emulator: Genymotion Nexus 5x API level 25

Comment: [link](https://i.udemycdn.com/redactor/raw/2019-07-19_06-23-29-28c63826f144460c57bd4e142c7d4e82.png) _italic_ **bold** `code`

[link](https://i.udemycdn.com/redactor/raw/2019-07-19_06-23-29-b3cbdc9e3c5731fa5cd810c552bb7121.png) _italic_ **bold** `code`

on my pc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting from 0, this is what i did:

1) `react-native init navigation`

2) `cd navigation`

3) `npm i react-navigation`

4) `npm i react-native-gesture-handler`

5) Copied your code inside App.js

6) `react-native start --reset-cache`

7) `react-native run-android`

My android simulator is a Nexus 5X API 28 X86 and works as expected.

Hope this helps you resolve this problem!

Comment: I did what you did with step-step...and worked...thanks for support :)

Answer (score 0):

Just Use

```
 index.ios.js
```

or

```
 index.andriod.js.
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, as you can see in the screenshot (below) of my debugger; for that, I closed the metro bundler and then re-run the app in the terminal. It works for me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

your importing createStackNavigator from the wrong pkg, you need to install react-navigation-stack and then import createStackNavigator from that pkg... hopes this solves your problem